# Error using google API and OAUTH2 in Python to get user info

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

My web app is successfully going through google's recommended flow to get credentials to query Google Drive API. This works fine. However, when I try to use the same credentials already obtained to get the user's email and name, I get an error.

*Here I retrieve credentials and query Google Drive API. This works perfectly fine*

```
def analyze():
 credentials = getCredentials() 
 drive_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
 theFiles = drive_service.files().list(pageSize=1000,q="trashed=false", fields="files(id,name,modifiedTime, size)").execute() #THIS WORKS
```

*Right after that, I try to use the SAME CREDENTIALS to get user info, but now it doesn't work*

```
oauth2_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('oauth2','v2',credentials=credentials)
 user_info= oauth2_client.userinfo().get().execute() #THIS FAILS
givenName = user_info['given_name']
```

Error: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json returned "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.">

*SOME OTHER IMPORTANT FUNCTIONS:*

```
def getCredentials():
 *Loads credentials from the session.*
 sc = session['credentials'] 
 credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token=sc.get('token'),
 client_id=sc.get('client_id'),
 refresh_token=sc.get('refresh_token'),
 token_uri=sc.get('token_uri'),
 client_secret=sc.get('client_secret'),
 scopes=sc.get('scopes'))
```

*the credentials are obtained in the callback page:*

```
@app.route('/OAcallback')
def OAcallback():
   flow =google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file('client_id.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'])
  flow.redirect_uri = return_uri
  authorization_response = request.url
  flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
  credentials = flow.credentials 
  * Store the credentials in the session.*
  credentials_to_dict(credentials)
```

Please help me understand why my credentials are not working when trying to get user info. What should I change?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only requesting the profile scope. To also request the email address add the scope `email`.

Change this part of your code from:

```
scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']
```

to:

```
scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' 'email']
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code to add email, but I am still getting the exact same error:

<HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json returned "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.">

Comment: 1) I do not see where you are storing your credentials in the session. Post complete code and not fragments. 2) Where in your code are you getting this error? 3) Show both the page where you authenticate the user and the page where you process the redirect.

Comment: One additional point. Once you changed the scopes in your code, you need to invalidate the old sessions.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley !!! I'm so stupid. The problem was originated by the fact I wasn't invalidating the old sessions. Once I corrected that, the program runs perfectly. I couldn't have discovered it without your help!

Comment: @ClementBjelland - You are welcome, glad to help. Don't forget to close this question.